# Creating the right data structure from my pdo calls

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to get programs and categories from a MySQL database. I can get the programs, and I can get the categories. I am struggling with creating an array or other data structure where `json_encode` will give me something like this:

{ 'CA' : [
  category1,
  category2
]
};

With the code that I have now, echoing my programsAr (json_encoded) I see

programsAr: [{"CA":[]},{"SNAP":[]}]

This is almost what I want, except that I want "CA" and "SNAP" to be keys in the same object, not different objects. I'm pretty new to PHP, and thus I'm not sure how to achieve this. If I could get both keys in the same object, I could easily iterate through the categories and add them by key.

Here's my code

```
  $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare("select id, name from TRACKER_PROGRAM where tracker = ?");
  $stmt2->execute(array($tracker));
  $combinedPrograms = array();
  $ids = array();
  $programsAr = array();
  while ($programs = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($combinedPrograms, array('id'=>$programs['id'],'name'=>$programs['name']));
    array_push($ids, $programs['id']);
    $arr = array();
    array_push($programsAr,array($programs['name']=>$arr));
  }
  echo 'programsAr: ' . json_encode($programsAr); 
  $stmt3 = $pdo->prepare("select TRACKER_PROGRAM.name as Program, PROGRAM_CATEGORY.name, PROGRAM_CATEGORY.ID from TRACKER_PROGRAM, PROGRAM_CATEGORY where program in (" .implode(',',$ids) . ") and TRACKER_PROGRAM.id = PROGRAM_CATEGORY.program order by program");
  $stmt3->execute();
  $topics = $stmt3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are pushing the array without specifying the key so it will be treated as new object not key => value

try this code using different syntax should give you what you need.

```
  $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare("select id, name from TRACKER_PROGRAM where tracker = ?");
  $stmt2->execute(array($tracker));
  $combinedPrograms = array();
  $ids = array();
  $programsAr = array();
  while ($programs = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $combinedPrograms[] = array('id'=>$programs['id'],'name'=>$programs['name']);
    $ids[] = $programs['id'];
    $arr = array();
    $programsAr[$programs['name']] = $arr;
  }
  echo 'programsAr: ' . json_encode($programsAr); 
  $stmt3 = $pdo->prepare("select TRACKER_PROGRAM.name as Program, PROGRAM_CATEGORY.name, PROGRAM_CATEGORY.ID from TRACKER_PROGRAM, PROGRAM_CATEGORY where program in (" .implode(',',$ids) . ") and TRACKER_PROGRAM.id = PROGRAM_CATEGORY.program order by program");
  $stmt3->execute();
  $topics = $stmt3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```